# Combining two relative paths with C#

Tags: c#, mono

There are many dupes for "appending a relative path to an absolute path", but I need to add relative to relative.

e.g.:

```
Path1 = "Parent/Child/a.txt"
Path2 = "../Sibling/file.cs"

Result = "Parent/Sibling/file.cs"
```

---

Tried:

- `Directory.GetParent()` - works, but I can't find a way to return the result (it can only return absolute paths)
- `Path.Combine()` - only works for simple cases and absolute paths. Fails (badly!) on the use of ".." with relative paths

...it seems absurd to write a string-tokenizing Path class to solve this, but I've been digging through the MSDN docs and can't seem to find a working Path/Directory class that correctly works with relative paths.

To make matters worse ... I'm trying to make this work all the way back to .NET 2 (thanks to Mono compatibilty)

Answer (score 1):

I know the following code is ugly but will work (sorry I don't confirm on mono yet):

```
var Result =
    Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path1), Path2))
    .Substring(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Length + 1); // +1 to remove leading path separator
```

Comment: Nice idea. GetCurrentDirectory() is unlikely to be the right base, but I'll try that with "Substring(Directory.GetDirectory(Path1))" or similar

Comment: No, doesn't work - I don't have a way to calculate the root folder of the relative path, in order to strip that off :(. It only takes 5 or so short lines of code to manually tokenize a path, remove a piece, and re-combine it :(.

Comment: I don't think that you need to know the base directory path for your relative path. I used `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` because `Path.GetFullPath` uses the current directory path to complement the relative path, as described [this document's Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you say `Path.Combine` fails badly, since you don't give any examples of what you've tried. But `Path.Combine` does exactly what you're looking for. You do have to give it a little help in this case; your first path is a filename, and you need the directory.

```
var filePath1 = "Parent/Child/a.txt";
var filePath2 = "../Sibling/file.cs";

var baseDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath1);
var result = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, filePath2);
```

This returns `"Parent\Child\../Sibling/file.cs"` rather than the `"Parent/Sibling/file.cs"` you're looking for, but the two paths are exactly equivalent.

Comment: "rather than the "Parent/Sibling/file.cs" you're looking for" -- well, exactly. It doesn't return what I'm looking for, it returns something else. The two things are clearly not "exactly equivalent". They resolve to the same location, but they are different paths.

Comment: If you can pass them both to the file APIs and get the exact same results, then that's pretty much the definition of "equivalent". Can you explain *why* the version with `..` won't work for you?

Comment: Because it's incorrect. That is not the final path, it's an expression that evaluates to the path. Try printing it. Try running your method multiple times. You will get a vile mess of "a/../b/../c/d/../../e/.." etc - which becomes increasingly fragile and likely not to evaluate properly (I have long experience of systems where "too many .." causes problems for library calls and utilities)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Windows, it should work on Mac OS (Mono/Xamarin) or Linux (Mono) but you might need a different value for the dummyDriveLetter variable.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Path1 = "Parent/Child/a.txt";
        string Path2 = "../Sibling/file.cs";

        string dummyDriveLetter = "C:/"; // must be an absolute path, so let's add a dummy prefix, works on Windows
        string absolutePath1 = dummyDriveLetter + Path1;

        var path1Uri = new Uri(absolutePath1, UriKind.Absolute);
        var path2Uri = new Uri(Path2, UriKind.Relative);
        var diff = new Uri(path1Uri, path2Uri);
        string Result = diff.OriginalString.Replace(dummyDriveLetter, "");

        Console.WriteLine(Result);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this with two paths: "some/paths/suck/toffee" and ""suck/toffee/sweets" - I was expecting "some/paths/suck/toffee/sweets", what I got was "some/paths/suck/suck/toffee/sweets" which is unexpected.