# C# Combining two relative network paths

Tags: c#, path

The System.IO.Path Methods gave me some really weird results while combining two paths;

```
string Dir = "\\server1\\customers\\Test";
string path = "..\\..\\customers\\Test\\hello.pbt";

path = Path.Combine(Dir, path);
// path = "\\server1\\customers\\Test\\..\\..\\customers\\Test\\hello.pbt"
```

now i want to combine these paths:

```
path = "\\server1\\customers\\Test\\hello.pbt" // aim
```

but with the Path.GetFullPath method, it doesnt go backwards to the server as it should

```
path = Path.GetFullPath(path)
// path = "\\server1\\customers\\customers\\Test\\hello.pbt"
```

I Already tried all methods in described in [Combining two relative paths with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710480/combining-two-relative-paths-with-c-sharp) answers

Comment: the Combine method simply concatenates the first with the second. Actually the result is not weird but to be expected. What are the rules of "combining" that would lead to the expected result?

Comment: yeah i know, but it should go backwards two times instead of one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that .NET (and maybe Windows) does not view the parent of `\\server1\customers` to be `\\server`.

It looks like technically `\\server` is not a [valid UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28167214/34092) (i.e. you can't store files there directly).

```
var thisWorks = Directory.GetParent(Dir);

var thisIsNull = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Dir).FullName);
```

Thus when you ask for `..\\..\\` it effectively ignores one of them since it deduces it can't go any higher up the directory tree...

Comment: many thanks to that answer!! you are totally right, the `server1` ist not a valid UNC path. i cant create anything in that "folder". It helped me to understand the problem

Comment: @tony_370 You are welcome. I didn't know it either, until I played with it myself just then and read up on it.

Comment: The `DirectoryInfo` show me that the server-path does not exist. Is there any functionality that resolve my `"..\"` nevertheless, without checking if the folder exists?

Comment: The short answer is you would need to write that yourself @tony_370.